# Laravel 5.2 Cache increment issue with expiration time

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5

I am adding a key to Cache for x minutes on first http request and then keep incrementing on next requests.

Issue I face is while incrementing, cache expire time also gets reset, I need to retain the expiry time. I also show expiry time in terms of seconds.

Below is my code:

```
$key = $input['device_id'];
if(! $attempts = Cache::get($key))
{
   Cache::put($key, 1, Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
}
else
{
  Cache::increment($key);
}
```

Comment: Why do this when Laravel comes with a [`RateLimiter`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.html) out of the box? There's also a `throttle` middleware already defined in the default laravel installation.

Comment: My throttling is only based on IP, I am using some other data like device unique ID. This api is for mobile apps, actually.

Comment: My point is RateLimiter seems to provide all the functionality you'd need.

Comment: Well, do you know any example where RateLimiter is used for custom unique key rather than on IP? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the built-in middleware `ThrottlesRequests` and attach it to your login route :

```
 class MyThrottleRequests extends \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottlesRequests {

      protected function resolveRequestSignature($input) {
              return $input->device_id; //I think this is what you mean to use right?
      }

 }
```

You can then specify it in your defined middleware in `Kernel.php`

```
  protected $routeMiddleware = [
       // Existing ones
       'throttleDeviceId' => MyThrottleRequests::class
  ];
```

You can then use it on your required routes as:

```
  \Route::any("/route/to/throttle",/* Route definition */)->middleware("throttle:<max requests>,<within time>");
```

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos for the recommendation. It works for me!